# Phantomjs / Casperjs opening bt wifi and login

Tags: authentication, automation, phantomjs, casperjs, scrape

okay can someone point me in the direction on how i can automate a login to my bt wifi stats and save the resulting HTML into a file

https://www.bt.com/wifi/secure/statuscheck.do

can anybody help me on achieving this i am new to phantom and Casper.

any help and advise will go a long way thanks

error code i am recieveng to answer below

```
Test file: C:\Users\ash\Downloads\aaaaaaaa\casper\n1k0-casperjs-4f105a9\batchbin\hello.js
FAIL Errors encountered while filling form: form not found
#    type: uncaughtError
#    file: C:\Users\ash\Downloads\aaaaaaaa\casper\n1k0-casperjs-4f105a9\batchbin\hello.js:802
#    error: Errors encountered while filling form: form not found
#           CasperError: Errors encountered while filling form: form not found
#               at fillForm (C:/Users/ash/Downloads/aaaaaaaa/casper/n1k0-casperjs-4f105a9/modules/casper.js:802)
#               at fillNames (C:/Users/ash/Downloads/aaaaaaaa/casper/n1k0-casperjs-4f105a9/modules/casper.js:862)
#               at C:\Users\ash\Downloads\aaaaaaaa\casper\n1k0-casperjs-4f105a9\batchbin\hello.js:5
#               at runStep (C:/Users/ash/Downloads/aaaaaaaa/casper/n1k0-casperjs-4f105a9/modules/casper.js:1553)
#               at checkStep (C:/Users/ash/Downloads/aaaaaaaa/casper/n1k0-casperjs-4f105a9/modules/casper.js:399)
#    stack: not provided
```

Comment: I think casper is a good way to do it. Did you already install it?

Comment: yes i have it installed i just need help on using it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thin you should use fill and gethtml function:

- http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#fill
- http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#gethtml

Quick program :

```
casper.start('https://www.bt.com/wifi/secure/statuscheck.do', function() {
    this.fill('form[name="LoginForm"]', {
       'username': 'LOGIN',
       'password': 'PASS'
    }, true); 
});

casper.wait(2000, function() {
    this.echo(this.getHTML());
});

casper.run();
```

Comment: thanks for this i have just made a js file with the above code but got a parse error i will now check out the links thanks

Comment: any chance u can tell me why i keep getting parse errors

Comment: Sorry i forgot a parenthesis.

Comment: okay bro i triued that but unfortunaty it cannot find the form i have edited my qeustion and include the output

Comment: i posted the out put in the question

Comment: That's odd no problem for me. Try to add a casper.capture('test.png'); before casper.fill to see what casper try to load.

Comment: i tried adding that to the code above unfortunatly i dont get a image :( i am new to casper sorry

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21352885/casperjs-cannot-find-login-form-i-have-selected-the-loginform?rq=1 my other post

Comment: this works brilliant now i have installed phantomjs and casperjs on ubuntu